# React.js:react-router-dom doesn't work in sidebar menu

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

[Updated]:
 adeed `Layout` and `Home` Components

I am a newbie in react.js. When I define all routes in App.js file, they work properly, but after separate routes and put in sidebar component, they not work(redirected to 404 page ).how to solve this problem?
tnx.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import Layout from "./containers/Layout/index";
import Home from "./containers/Home/index";
import NotFound from "./ui/ErroPages/NotFound/index"

var app = document.getElementById("app");

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
    <Layout>//my sidebar component inside Layout component there is
        <Switch>
           <Route path="/" exact component={Home} ></Route>         
           <Route path="*"  component={NotFound}></Route>
            //if Route Test defined here it`s work properly
        </Switch>
    </Layout>
</BrowserRouter>
    ,app
);
if (module.hot) {
     module.hot.accept();
}
```

Sidebar component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Link, } from 'react-router-dom';
import Test from '../../containers/Test/index';

import '../../assets/img/Douran-logo.jpg';


const sidebar = () => {
    return (
        <aside className="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
            <div className="sidebar">
                <div>
                    <nav className="mt-2">
                        <ul className="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
                            <li className="nav-item has-treeview">
                                <Link to="/test" className="nav-link">
                                    <i className="nav-icon fa fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                                    <p>
                                        داشبورد
                                    </p>
                                </Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Route path="/test" component={Test}></Route>                
        </aside>    
    );
}
```

my `Layout` Component

```
class Layout extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
           <div> 
                <Header />
                <Sidebar />
                    <div className="content-wrapper">
                          //All contents is included here(Home,Test,...)
                    </div>     
                <Footer />
                <ControlSidebar/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

My `Home` Component

```
    class Home extends React.Component {
    render(){
    return(
        <section className="content">
            {/* <!-- Default box --> */}
            <div className="card">
                <div className="card-header">
                    <h3 className="card-title">داشبورد</h3>

                    <div className="card-tools">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-tool" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse">
                            <i className="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-tool" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove">
                            <i className="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    لورم ایپسوم متن ساختگی با تولید سادگی نامفهوم از صنعت چاپ و با استفاده از طراحان گرافیک است.
          </div>
                {/* <!-- /.card-body --> */}
                <div className="card-footer">
                    فوتر
          </div>
                {/* <!-- /.card-footer--> */}
            </div>
            {/* <!-- /.card --> */}
        </section>
        // {/* <!-- /.content --> */}
    );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Hi rohullah, please try my solution below and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you keep your `Route` outside of `Switch`, `NotFound` component get visible for all `Route` outside of `Switch`. 
For Example,

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <Layout/>   => This component conatins <Route path="/test" component={Test}></Route>
   <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} ></Route>         
      <Route path="*"  component={NotFound}></Route>
      //if Route Test defined here it`s work properly
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

When you click a `Link` to get `Test` component, you will get `Test` component as well as `NotFound` component. Because `<Route path="/test" component={Test}></Route>` is not inside of `Switch`.

**My suggestion is to keep your `Route` at one place only, and i.e. in `Switch`.**

As you want your `Layout` should be like this,

```
<div> 
   <Header />
   <Sidebar />
   <div className="content-wrapper">
       //All contents is included here(Home,Test,...)
   </div>     
   <Footer />
   <ControlSidebar/>
</div>
```

I suggest you to keep your `Route` in `Layout` component only,

```
<div>
    <Header />
    <Sidebar />
    <div className="content-wrapper">
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Sidebar />  //Don't write any <Route> inside of Sidebar component
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Home}></Route>
                <Route path="/test" component={Test}></Route>  
                <Route path="*" component={NotFound}></Route>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
    <Footer />
    <ControlSidebar />
</div>
```

And directly mount `Layout` component,

```
ReactDOM.render(<Layout />,app);
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fabufu)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap your `Routes` inside the `Layout` Component. Just define your `Routes` outside the `Layout` and within `BrowserRouter`. This is required for the `Routes` to work properly since `BrowserRouter` needs a way to detect where the `Routes` are within their children tree. For better readability, my example will include an overall App component.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import Layout from "./containers/Layout/index";
import Home from "./containers/Home/index";
import NotFound from "./ui/ErroPages/NotFound/index"

var app = document.getElementById("app");

const App = () => {
   return(
     <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
           <Layout/>
           <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact component={Home} ></Route>         
              <Route path="*"  component={NotFound}></Route>
              //if Route Test defined here it`s work properly
           </Switch>
        </div>

     </BrowserRouter>
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,app);
```

It also might make more sense to just have the `Sidebar` component on its own and not inside the `Layout` component if you don't plan on showing `Layout` at all times.

Comment: thank you...but after modify App.js  according to your solution, the main content dose not appear and routing problem still remains

Comment: The main content does not appear? I find that quite strange. Wouldn't the Home component at least appear?

Comment: Yes...Unfortunately `Home` component dose not appear. i updated first post and inserted `Home` and `Layout` components..tnx

Answer (score 0):

```
<div> 
   <Header />
   <Sidebar />
   <div className="content-wrapper">
      
   </div>     
   <Footer />
   <ControlSidebar/>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.